# Как используя Laravel и PHP 8 записывать текст в базу MaiaDB через модель избегая проблем со спецсимволами?

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование, pdo

Есть необходимость хранить в базе разметку html. Для этого используется поле с типом данных **longtext**.

```
$model = new ModesDoc;

$model->length = count($info['content']);
$model->content = $info['content'];
$model->timestamp = time();

$model->save();
```

Иногда при попытке записать данные в базу, Laravel выдает ошибку

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC8\xED\xF2\xE5\xF0\xED...' for column `mdbs`.`check_url`.`content` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `check_url` (`content_length`, `content`, `timestamp`) values (318670, ...
```

Судя по тому, что он ругается на Invalid datetime format я предположу, что где-то в тексте разметки есть служебные символы, которые оказывают влияние на итоговый sql-запрос. В мануале https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php я не нашел нужных констант, да и функция mysql_real_escape_string уже давно исключена из PHP. Как можно такое пофиксить?

Comment: Насчет timestamp - при создании таблицы надо указывать дефолтным CURRENT_TIMESTAMP и не нужно "вручную" время добавлять... и есть предположение что надо для базы  `SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

Comment: @indevx CURRENT_TIMESTAMP имеет смысл использовать тогда, когда важно зафиксировать время создания записи в базе, а не время самой непосредственной операции. Т.е. важно понимать имеет ли тут влияние лаг по времени или нет. Ну это так... А по сути вопроса: для базы и для всех таблиц используется utf8mb4_unicode_ci (т.е. проблема не в этом).

Comment: 1. Иногда сообщения об ошибках вводят в заблуждение 2. Покажите последнюю часть от `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format:` там где timestamp. 3. Также покажите какой тип в БД этот timestamp - можно через `show create table modes_docs`